# RequireJS Module name "requirejs" has not been loaded yet for context. use require([])

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, requirejs

I know there is a help page for a module not loading, however, this seems like a different case due to the fact that requirejs cannot find requirejs.

I installed all of my dependencies using npm. My main script is in the project root, which is called by an html page.

Here is a snippet from the web page:

`<script type="text/javascript" data-main="./airportLeafletScript.js" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>`

And then the header of airportLeafletScript.js looks like this:

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
//Pass the top-level main.js/index.js require
//function to requirejs so that node modules
//are loaded relative to the top-level JS file.
nodeRequire: require
});

requirejs(['turf', 'jquery', 'leaflet', 'leaflet-rotatedmarker', 
    'leaflet-slider', 'shpjs', 'jquery-ui', 'json3', 'esri-leaflet'],
    function   (turf, $, L, Marker, SliderControl, shp) {
 //foo and bar are loaded according to requirejs
 //config, but if not found, then node's require
 //is used to load the module.
});
```

The actual error message is:

```
11:03:19.078 Error: Module name "requirejs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
makeError() require.js:168
localRequire() require.js:1433
requirejs() require.js:1794
<anonymous> airportLeafletScript.js:46
1 require.js:168:17
```

So how can I get requirejs working for this project? It doesn't seem to be configured properly

Answer (score 2):

The code you are showing that does `var requirejs = require('requirejs');` is meant to be run in Node.js, not in a browser. Also note the configuration passed to `requirejs.config` which includes `nodeRequire`, which only makes sense in Node.js.

When you load that code in a browser with the `script` tag that you show, RequireJS is *already* loaded, and the `require` call tries to load it again, which is bad no matter how you cut it. It happens to trigger a RequireJS-specific error but that's a side-effect of trying to load code written for Node.js through RequireJS.

When you load the same code in Node.js, the `require` call is handled by Node.js. It load RequireJS and then you can configure it and use it.