# Require statement error on importing modules from TestRunner.html

Tags: mocha.js

I am new to mocha. My scripts below works when i run from the `terminal`. However, there is no result when i run from testrunner.html. On checking, it seems to be because of `var xl = require('./excel');`. if i comment this statement, it works. How can i make this work? i need to import custom modules for my script.

**Updated test.js to incorporate RequireJS**

- Post changes: works on browser and termial

**module1.js**

```
if(typeof define !== 'undefined')
{
    define([], function() {
        return {
            get: function() {
                return get();
            }
        };
    });
}
else if(typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = {
        get: function(){
            return get();
        }    
    };    
}

function get(){
    return "hello node world";
}
```

**test.js**

```
if(typeof requirejs == 'undefined') {var requirejs = require('requirejs');}
if(typeof chai == 'undefined') {var chai = require('chai');}
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '.',
    paths: {   

    },
    nodeRequire: require
});

describe("RequireTest()", function(){    
    var module1;
    before(function(done){
        requirejs(['./module1'], 
            function(_module) {                    
                console.log('before fired');
                module1 = _module;  
                if(typeof requirejs == 'undefined') {mocha.run();}
                done();             
        });
    });        
    it('test case: ', function(){
        console.log(module1.get());
        chai.expect(1+1).to.equal(2);
    });
});
```

**testrunner.html (snippet)**

```
<div id="mocha"></div>
<script src="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>

<script src="./test.js"></script>

<script>mocha.run();</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run Mocha at the command line you are using Node.js, which provides `require`.

When you run it in the browser, there is no `require` that the browser provides. You need to use a module loader at run-time like RequireJS or SystemJS. Or you need to use a packager like Webpack or Browserify that will process your code beforehand and turn it into a single bundle that incorporates all your code.

Note that whether third-party modules you use can be loaded in a browser, is a determination you have to make module-by-module. If you use a module that uses Node's `child_process` module to spawn a new process, for instance, you won't be able to just use that module in the browser because browsers don't provide `child_process`.

Comment: thanks. I have updated the original question to use `RequireJS` based on my understanding of the readup's. And, i am still stuck trying to get it run on the browser. Please advise.

Comment: hello @Louis, i just updated the original test.js to use `RequireJS`. It runs from the terminal. But, not via the browser. What could be the missing gap? thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get in the browser? Remember in my answer I mention that some node modules won't run in the browser. That may be your issue. Recalling from your other question, it seems to me you want to read from the filesystem. You cannot do this in the browser (at list not as a direct conversion from Node to browser code: the browser does not provide anything like [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).)

Comment: This is what i get on the browsers Dev tools. `require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Module name "requirejs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

Comment: Hello @Louis, Need your help. Kindly refer the update script in the original question. update made based on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355903](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355903). `Current result is: ` it works on the terminal. But does not work on browser. No Error is shown either.

Comment: Hi @Louis, thanks for your patient hearing and explanations. Finally got it to work on both the browser and the terminal. I have updated the original question so that it may help others like me. Is there a better way to do the same thing?